# .NET Core controller : GET how to receive multiple parameters in route

Tags: .net-core, routes, controller

I have a .NET Core controller action method in `FileController` like this:

```
[HttpGet("{filename}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] string filename, int take, int skip = 0)
{
    // process file
}
```

So it gets the filename from the route.

Is there any way to get the values of `take` and `skip` also from the route?

Instead of adding them to the body of the request.

So a request would look like:

```
https://localhost:43845/File/myfilename.txt/10/1
```

So take would be 10 and skip would be 1

Comment: I wouldn't do that - the URL describes the **resource** - but the take and skip are **not** part of the resource, they're just "additional" information - so they really shouldn't be part of the URL either. I would pass them in as query parameters - `/file/myfilename.txt?page=1&pageSize=10`. Plus - take and skip typically only apply to **collections** of resources - to `/files` - not to a **single** resource like a single file....

Comment: exactly what I wanted but can't mark a comment as a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do that - the URL describes the resource - but the `Take` and `Skip` are not part of the resource, they're just "additional" information (sometimes called "metadata") - so they really shouldn't be part of the URL either.

I would pass them in as query parameters like this:

```
/file/myfilename.txt?take=10&skip=2
```

Additionally - `Take` and `Skip` are typically only applied to **collections** of resources, so to a call to `/files` - not to a single resource like just that one file in your request.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by adding parameters through `[HttpGet]`

```
[HttpGet("{filename}/{take}/{skip?}")]
```